# How can I introduce dependence (to varying degrees) into a synthetic dataset to measure the effect on my method?

Tags: independence, synthetic-data

I'm using a synthetic dataset in which I sample from three independent Bernoulli random variables x1, x2 and x3 with p=p1, p=p2 and p=p3 respectively. I wish to "introduce dependence," or make the variables no longer independent to varying degrees.

I tried to do this by introducing another random variable, x0, such that features are only conditionally independent on x0. Specifically, I sample first from x0, and using this outcome in the construction of the features, such that x1_i = x0_i with probability p_d and Bernoulli(p1) with probability 1-p_d. This introduces dependence between the features with increasing p_d (correct me if I'm wrong!) but also fundamentally changes the dataset, including the marginal distributions of the features.

Because there are only 8 outcomes total, I've also considered directly sampling from a joint distribution, and modifying the matrix in a way that maintains the marginals but breaks independence.

Is there a straightforward way of introducing feature dependence in a synthetic dataset that maintains the marginal feature distributions or otherwise maintains the properties of the dataset?

Other ideas are also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Vance.  "Introducing dependence" describes essentially all of probabilistic modeling.  You need to tell us more specifically about your data and the form of dependence you need.

Comment: +1 -- thank you for the details.  There's no need to keep the original, though: that will always be available in the edit record for anyone who is curious.  Deleting that (now) extraneous material will make your post more accessible, increasing the chance it will attract good answers.

Comment: Re the ultimate question of "maintaining the properties of the dataset:" is there any reason you don't simply resample (with replacement) from the dataset itself?

Comment: Could you say more about what this could look like? How would I introduce dependence in this case?

Comment: Resampling would reproduce every property of the "dataset" to which you refer.

Comment: Can you explain more about how this would introduce varying levels of dependency? E.g., how would I sample from the dataset to get more or less dependency?

Comment: I am not understanding your situation, so let's back up.  It appears you have a dataset.  Could you explain what it means to "get more or less dependency" in it and why you want to do so?